grpc ssl connect failed: Security handshake failed description":"Socket closed"
We use the official grpc example, and it is normal for the SSL channel of the synchronous API to establish communication. But when we use our project, SSL communication is failed:

grpc_log(18) > file
[/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/grpc-1.42.0/src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc],
line [181], msg[Security handshake failed:
{"created":"@156.548837962","description":"Handshake read
failed","file":"/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/grpc-1.42.0/src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":456,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@156.548814129","description":"Socket
closed","fd":24,"file":"/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/grpc-1.42.0/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":764,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:168.250.250.1:40644"}]}]

We use synchronous API example and set GRPC_SSL_TARGET_NAME_OVERRIDE_ARG param, i expect the communcation normally.

Please include evidence that there's something listening on 168.250.250.1:40644

The log belongs to server side. How do I prove it's listening? Client log shows below: failed, server:168.250.250.2:5200, cost: 0ms, code:14, msg:failed to connect to all addresses.
